# How to show message on plugins activation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WordPress currently I developing one extension for WooCommerce. So when user going to activate my extension without having WooCommerce plugins, I want to show them one warning message.

How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can show messages with add_action('admin_notices', 'my_plugin_admin_notices');

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_plugin_admin_notices');
function my_plugin_admin_notices() {
    if (!is_plugin_active('plugin-directory/plugin-file.php')) {
        echo "<div class='updated'><p>Message to be shown</p></div>";
    }
}
```

if you want the message to be shown only once you can use options:

```
if (!get_option('my_plugin_notice_shown') && !is_plugin_active('plugin-directory/plugin-file.php')) {
    echo "<div class='updated'><p>Message to be shown</p></div>";
    update_option('my_plugin_notice_shown', 'true');
}
```

Comment: I suggest the class 'error', instead of 'updated', for this particular use case.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply check through below code in any file :

```
if($_GET['activate'] == true){

}
```

or

```
function _my_plugin_php_warning() {
    echo '<div id="message" class="error">';
    echo '  <p>Your Message</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}

function activate_plugin_conditional() {
        $plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
        if ( is_plugin_active($plugin) ) {
            add_action('admin_notices', '_my_plugin_php_warning');
            }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'activate_plugin_conditional' );
```

Thanks.